# Xcode 3 and Xcode 4, what's the difference?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I want to start developing Games for apple iPhone and iPads but I have some related questions. I have mac running MAC OS X Leopard 10.5.5. So only supported version of Xcode for Leopard 10.5.5 is Xcode 3 so I want to know:

Is it ok to start to develop in Xcode 3? Will it work on all iPhones and iPad versions?
Or should I have to buy new mac running Lion to install Xcode 4 and develop App on that?

What are the drawbacks of using Xcode 3?

Comment: I like to stress legal's statement to buy a new Mac. You will get into tons of trouble since you can't use the latest technologies and, even more importantly, can't effectively test you app on newer iOS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it ok to start to develop in Xcode 3?

It's ok, but in Xcode 3 you cannot take advantage of many of the new features in Xcode 4 like ARC and storyboards. Additionally, Xcode 3 does not support the latest version of Objective-C; it supports Objective-C 2.0, which lacks many new features being introduced with the release of iOS 6.

> Will it work on all iPhones and iPad versions?

No. Using Xcode 3, you can only develop applications for older devices, I believe every iOS version below 4.0 (not sure).

> Or should I have to buy new mac running Lion to install Xcode 4 and develop App on that?

I recommend that you buy a new mac running Lion to install Xcode 4 in order to stay up to date with the latest features of Objective-C and Xcode, so as not to be left behind when competing developers utilize the latest features of the phone to create a better all-around user experience.

> What are the drawbacks of using Xcode 3?

- In Xcode 3, Xcode and Interface Builder are separate, as oppose to Xcode 4, where they are integrated.
- Xcode 3 does not support storyboards which greatly eases the process of designing your interface.
- Xcode 3 does not support ARC, which simplifies greatly memory management.
- Xcode 4 has a new feature called the Assistant Editor which complements the file you're working on. For example, if you're - working on the header file for a class called "MyClass", the assistant editor will display the implementation file.
- Xcode 4 has much better autocompletion than Xcode 3; it supports the new "Fix-It" feature which will not only point out errors in your code, but provide solutions to fix these errors.
- Xcode 4 works with Git to provide powerful source control management.

For more info on the differences between Xcode 3 and Xcode 4, see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanx qegal for quick response... your answer cleared all my doubts... one more question plz i'm going to develop game in cocos2d Still will i have to download xcode and ios sdk both???

Comment: Yep. You have to download Xcode and the iOS SDK, and then install cocos2D from here: <http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download> Installing cocos2D will place cocos2D application templates in the Xcode "New Project" menu.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update the xcode to 4, since you will not be able to use iOS5 features, also to distribute your application to the Appstore you need the a newer version of xcode

Comment: so you means that if i develop my App Using Xcode3 it will be not eligible to sell on app store???

Comment: it depends will you use features of iOS5?